# Python sendmail error script

Tags: python, sendmail

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import smtplib

sender = 'from@fromdomain.com'
receivers = ['to@todomain.com']

message = """From: From Person <from@fromdomain.com>
To: To Person <TEST@yahoo.com>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is a test e-mail message.
"""

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
   print "Successfully sent email"
except SMTPException:
   print "Error: unable to send email"
```

I keep getting the folllowing errors even though I imported everything. I'm using Linux, what's missing?

```
  File "email.py", line 3, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 46, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "/home/email.py", line 19, in <module>
    except SMTPException:
```

Comment: Your backtrace looks weird and incomplete -- is that the whole thing?

Comment: @Dougal I erased the rest for privacy reasons. ralu No, I'm on my university's Linux server

Comment: @user1022944 It's a little hard to tell what the problem is without seeing more of the error. Can you just replace any server names or whatnot with example.com and post that?

Comment: then replace localhost whit working smtp server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only obvious thing that should not work is that `SMTPException` needs to be `smtplib.SMTPException` (or import it for unqualified use with `from smtplib import SMTPException`).

Otherwise, after changing to my own (valid) addresses and my own SMTP server, your code works fine.